# Flutter store and retrieve date as YYYMM. Is Model Class the right place to do it?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, model-view-controller

For my ***Flutter*** application, I need the 'date' to be stored in Firestore as either 'YYYYMM' or 'YYYYMMDD' (Number) instead of as a Firestore Timestamp.  However, to use the various date widgets, I may have to convert them into a Timestamp object to use DatePicker, etc.

So should I do this conversion in the **Model Class or in the helper method** that does the writing to the Firebase Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

You mean you need to use the `DateTime` class instead of the `Timestamp` class?

I would use the model class. In this class define the data type for date as a `Number`. Create a setter method like this:

```
...
Number dateNumber;
...
void set date(DateTime inDate) {
  // put your conversion algorithm here
  dateNumber = ...
}
```

Later:

```
data.date = DateTime.now(); // for example
```

Comment: No. I'm currently using DateTime instead of TimeStamp in the model.
`DateTime openDate`
and I want to continue to use that.

However, in the toJSON and fromJSON methods in the model which converts the value to database and from database respectively, I want to convert this DateTime to number and vice versa.

But declaring a 'set' method on the date doesn't work as I get the error that setter is already defined!

Comment: Sorry. We need to call the field something else. See my corrected reply. Dart creates an automatic setter and getter with the same name as the field name.